# How to build all subdirectories?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want `cargo build` to build every package in a subdirectory of the current directory and likewise with `cargo check`.

What should be in `Cargo.toml` in the current directory?

(The current directory itself does not contain any software, only its subdirectories with interdependent applications and libraries.)

Comment: I think you are looking for [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Herohtar in the comment.

You would want to create `Cargo.toml` file in your current directory. Where only a `workspace` configuration is present, that names all the crates that you have in your sub directories.

```
[workspace]

members = [
    "dir1",
    "dir2",
]
```

then a regular `cargo build` would build them all.